# клик по инпут отрабатывает вторая функция

Tags: javascript, jquery

где ошибся?
при нажатии на `$('input[name="count"]').bind('click keyup', function(){}` выводит не результат в этой функции а результат  `$('input[name="count"]').bind('click keydown', function(){}`

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('input[name="count"]').bind('click keyup', function(){
    $count = 0
    $pricenorm = 0;
    $count = $('input[name="count"]').val(); 
    $p1 = $('.p1').html().replace(/ /g,"");
    $p2 = $('.p2').html().replace(/ /g,"");
    $p3 = $('.p3').html().replace(/ /g,"");
    $p4 = $('.p4').html().replace(/ /g,"");
    $p5 = $('.p5').html().replace(/ /g,"");
    $p6 = $('.p6').html().replace(/ /g,"");
    $p7 = $('.p7').html().replace(/ /g,"");

    $pricenorm = $('.pricein').html().replace(/ /g,"");
    if ($count>=1 && $count<=4){
       $alls = $count*$p1
    }else
    {
      if ($count>=5 && $count<=20) 
     {
       $alls = $count*$p2
     }else{
         if ($count>=21 && $count<=50) 
         {
           $alls = $count*$p3
         }else{
            if ($count>=51 && $count<=100) 
             {
               $alls = $count*$p4
             }else{
                 if ($count>=101 && $count<=300) 
                 {
                   $alls = $count*$p5
                 }else{
                     if ($count>=301 && $count<=500) 
                     {
                       $alls = $count*$p6
                     }else{
                        $alls = $count*$p7 
                     };
                 };
             };
         };
     };   
    };
    $('.priceout').html(' ');
    $('.priceout').html($alls.toFixed(2));
    });


    $('input[name="count"]').bind('click keydown', function(){
    $count = 0
    $pricenorm = 0;
    $count = $('input[name="count"]').val(); 
    $pricenorm = $('.pricein').html().replace(/ /g,"");
    $alls = $count*$pricenorm;
    $('.priceout').html(' ');
    $('.priceout').html($alls.toFixed(2));
    });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: ...приведи [MCVE]

Comment: если про нажатие мыши, то что последнее прибиндено, то и выводит. Если клавиши, то она сначала нажимается, потом отпускается. в любом случае закономерно что  в результате будет `click keydown`

Comment: а как исправить, чтобы выполнялось только то по чему кликаем

Comment: дак не биндите вторую функцию к клику, если вам это не надо

Comment: а если я нажал в инпут на keydown как мне это обработать?